# Compute gaussian fit corresponding to a discrete variable

Tags: fitting

I collected data for a discrete probability distribution and I have the pairs (value, probability).

```
Value    Probability
 90      0,0033
125      0.0204
180      0.0847
250      0.2516
355      0.4653
500      0.175
710      0.0015
```

I have been asked to compute a gaussian fit over that data but I am having troubles.
Is it possible (and does it make sense) to fit a gaussian distribution over it?

I tried to build the corresponding gaussian distribution by computing mean (`334`) and standard deviation (`100`) of my data but, of course, it does not work.

Gaussian density function values are related to continuous values while the probability I have are continuous.

I guess that I have too few discrete values to compute the gaussian distribution, but I am not really into statistics so I am not sure and I'd like to double check with you that I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "Gaussian fit" to a discrete probability distribution makes little or no sense in statistical applications, but mathematically almost a perfect fit can be made to these *ordered pairs*.  Just find values $m$ and $s$ for which the *cumulative* Gaussian $$\Phi(x;m,s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi s^2}}\int_{-\infty}^x \exp(-(t-m)^2/s^2)  dt$$ closely agrees with the data.

To illustrate the computation, here is an example of least-squares fitting (in R).  Because the probabilities do not sum exactly to $1$, it standardizes them to sum to unity.

```
# The data
x <- c(90, 125, 180, 250, 355, 500, 710)
p <- c(0.0033, 0.0204, 0.0847, 0.2516, 0.4653, 0.1750, 0.0015)

# Standardize the cumulative probabilities
prob <- cumsum(p); prob <- prob / prob[7]

# Compute sum of squared residuals to a fit
f <- function(q) {
  res <- pnorm(x, q[1], q[2]) - prob
  sum(res * res)
}

# Find the least squares fit
coeff <-(fit <- nlm(f, c(334, 100)))$estimate

# Plot the fit
plot(x, prob)
curve(pnorm(x, coeff[1], coeff[2]), add=TRUE)
```

[image: Plot]

The optimal values are $m \approx 279.5$, $s \approx 80.5$.